# In function ‘main’: hungry.c:12:25: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token

Tags: c, ubuntu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define LB_SIZE 1024

int main()(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     char full Pathname[] = /usr/X11R6/bin/xeyes;
     char *myArgv[LB_SIZE];  

     myArgv[0] = malloc(strlen(fullPathName) + 1);
     strcpy(myArgv[0], fullPathName);
     myArgv[1] = NULL;  
     execvp(fullPathName, myArgv);

     exit(0);  
}
```

Comment: We expect to see efforts on your part to solve the problem.SO is not *Get your homework done* forum. Please remember to quote your problems & Your efforts both when you ask Questions. since you are a new user, please do read the FAQ before asking Q's.

Comment: When I compile the source code you posted, I get 5 serious error messages *before* the problem you're asking about.  I don't believe that the code you posted is the same as the code you compiled.  If you want help, show us *real* code and *real* error messages; copy-and-paste it, don't re-type it.

Answer (score 2):

The character string should be enclosed in quotes:

```
char fullPathname[] = "/usr/X11R6/bin/xeyes";
                      ^                    ^
                      |                    |
```

Comment: now it gives this error hungry.c:9:5: error: ‘main’ declared as function returning a function

Comment: you need to change the definition of main to be `int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])`

Answer (score 0):

As @Als has said, strings should be enclosed in `"mystring text"` quotes.

I really think you need to start *learning* C before coding in it. Here are some recommendations:

- [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)
- [C Programming: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393969452)
- [C: The Complete Reference](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Complete-Reference-Osborne/dp/0072121246)

If you don't want to buy a book, try this free [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming).  I actually contributed a [chapter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/GObject) to it, so please give it good ratings :).